# Filter CSV rows to return a chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm struggling to get this code to work

```
var theBeeyatch = d3.csv("data/SalesDUMP.csv", function(csv) {

    csv = csv.filter(function(row) {
        return row['Year'] == '2012' || row['Month'] == '1';
    })
});

var Chart = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 200)

    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(theBeeyatch)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {return i * 20 + 20;})
    .attr("y", 100)
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", function (d) {return d.Year;});
```

The CSV file looks like this

```
Year,Month,ProductClass,Sales
2011,1,BA  ,28840
2011,1,BH  ,2800
2011,1,MB  ,1103200
2012,1,BA  ,70680
2012,1,MB  ,1596000
2012,1,_OTH,1530
2013,1,BA  ,120513.6
2013,1,BH  ,17640
2013,1,MB  ,1852761.6
```

I've tried filtering it as a string aswell. I have also tried parsing it as an integer.

There is no error in the console, but nothing appears on screen. I've searched high and low but have found nothing that's helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the d3 library very well, but it looks as though the `d3.csv` call is asynchronous.  Your `theBeeyatch` variable won't have any meaningful data when the function  returns.  Perhaps this would work:

```
var theBeeyatch = d3.csv("data/SalesDUMP.csv", function(csv) {
    csv = csv.filter(function(row) {
        return row['Year'] == '2012' || row['Month'] == '1';
    });

    var Chart = d3.select("body")
        // ...
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(csv)
        // ...
});
```

Of course you don't need the `theBeeyatch` variable here now, but perhaps you need it elsewhere...